# Why doesn't my GFCI trip when shorting hot to ground?

Tags: wiring

I have a good ground to a GFCI. I test from hot to ground and it doesn't trip. I get 119v from hot to ground. I installed a new GFCI. Same thing, won't trip. Hot and neutral on line side of GFCI.

Comment: How are you testing from hot to ground? Does the TEST button on the GFI work? How do you know you have a good ground?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. You'll note that this is a Question & Answer forum. Please [edit] your question to actually ask us a question (and ask a summary question in the title). As it is, you've only made several statements and "WTF" isn't really a question that deserves an answer...

Comment: @crip659 Except for the "line side". Touching hot to ground on the line side is not recommended, but it wouldn't trip the GFCI, because the GFCI is between "line" and "load".

Comment: why do you expect it to trip ?

Comment: @JACK  Bad wording, will try to fix.

Comment: If using a multi-meter correctly it should not cause a trip of the GFCI or breaker.  There are some GFCI testers that do have a button to test the GFCI trip.

Comment: @crip659 **All** GFCI testers have a button to test the GFCI trip, that's their raison detre. I think you mean *There are some **receptacle** testers...*

Comment: "Hot and neutral on line side of GFCI." -- are you shorting the line side? The GFI device only protects the load side.

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is that you are testing incorrectly, not that you have two "bad" GFCIs in a row. Since you have not clearly described your test procedure, and what you have said is wildly abnormal (**shorting** hot to ground? Uh, don't do that, use a resistor - better yet, buy a tester with a resistor inside it) you'll need to clarify exactly what you have done so someone not standing there can point out the error. *i.e.* if you short the line terminal for hot to ground, I'd expect a big spark and a tripped breaker, but the GFCI won't care, that being not in it's bailiwick.

Comment: You could possibly test a GFCI receptacle by shorting the NEUTRAL to ground although this would give different results depanding on the loading on the circuit, but only do this after you have tested the receptacle and are sure it is correctly wired, and it would be a good idea to cover the hot slot with a little piece of tape to insure that you do not incorrectly insert the shorting conductor in the hot slot.

Comment: Shorting from hot to ground should blind you with arc flash. Clearly it's not doing that since you can type.  So maybe instead of using wackadoodle alternative methods of testing, use the methods described in the instructions.

Answer (score 4):

A GFCI should not trip unless current between hot and neutral is unbalanced.

The built in test, and plug-in testers, put a high-value resistor between hot and ground, leaking just enough current to  be considered a fault.

A voltmeter (which seems to be what you are using) normally has a much higher resistance than that, and will probably not permit enough current to flow to be considered a fault.

So: EXACTLY what are you doing to try to test the GFCI? It sounds like you aren't testing correctly.

(Also: Note that many GFCIs are shipped in the tripped state, and can not be reset except when powered.)